# Create anchor links in URL that includes trailing slashes

Tags: html, react-hooks, gatsby, trailing-slash, anchor-scroll

I have a react app (react hooks) using strapi and gatsby.
The URLs look like `http://localhost:8000/en/`. Note at the end of the link is a trailing slash.

A few navbar links should scroll to specific sections on the homepage using anchor links.
Due to the trailing slash the app would understand the anchor link as a new site which would then redirect to a 404 page.

Example:

```
http://localhost:8000/en/#section1/
```

even when hardcoding the link as `/en#section1/` the slash would still be set between `/en` and `#section1`. This would have the same result => `http://localhost:8000/en/#section1`

Is it possible to create an anchor nav in an app that has trailing slashes without actually removing the trailing slashes?